# Set a form element in error in case Save Form Failed

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml

I am validating my Custom Admin form on the server side. 
In the model, on _beforeSave() I throw an exception if there is something wrong with a specific field.

Now, the point is that the error from the exception is catched in the save of the controller :

```
    try {
    ...
        } catch (Exception $e) {
                                    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                                    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);

$this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
                                    return;
                                }
```

and will be displayed on the top of the page (addError), how can I put some kind of focus on the field that should be fixed?
Anything that can be done without using Javascript?

Thanks